# tyk fails to build on windows

Tags: go, tyk

I am trying to build tyk on windows. I am getting error.

```
..\..\pkg\mod\rsc.io\letsencrypt@v0.0.1\lets.go:269:9: undefined: acme.RegistrationResource
```

This is due RegistrationResource struct is missing in lego\acme. I can see this is due to incompatibility between letsencrypt and lego.

Is there anything which I can try out?

Answer (score 0):

Tyk is not designed to be run on windows at all. If you need to use it on a windows system I would recommend installing in docker or a unix based VM.

https://tyk.io/docs/get-started/with-tyk-on-premise/installation/docker/

Thanks
Josh